# Spring MVC: Deserialise query parameters to POJO using Jackson objectMapper

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, deserialization, jackson2

Spring web application configuration contains Jackson `ObjectMapper` configured like this

```
  objectMapper.disable(ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
  objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
```

`JavaTimeModule` is added to handle deserialisation of `ZonedDateTime`. There are two endpoint which handle a POJO which contains `ZonedDateTime`. The POJO is like this:

```
class MyRequest {
  ZonedDateTime from
  ZonedDateTime to
}
```

and controller with endpoints is:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
class MyController {

  @GetMapping('/pojo')
  void getPojo(MyRequest myRequest) {
    log.debug("Request received: $myRequest")
  }

  @PostMapping('/pojo')
  void postPojo(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
    log.debug("Request received: $myRequest")
  }
}
```

When I send POST /pojo with body

```
{"from": "2017-03-15T00:00:00Z", "to": "2017-03-16T00:00:00Z"}
```

The response is 200 and deserialisation is successful.

Contrary, when I send

```
GET /pojo?from=2017-03-15T00:00:00Z&to=2017-03-15T00:00:00Z
```

The 400 Bad Request is received with error

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2017-03-15T00:00:00Z'
```

This make sense, since in GET request, I'm not sending JSON and therefore JSON object mapper is not called.

Is there a way to use `objectMapper` for GET requests also, so query parameters are converted into POJO object?

By the way, I know that it can be deserialised for GET endpoint like below, but I want to use same converter for GET and POST endpoint

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
ZonedDateTime from
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
ZonedDateTime to
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Injecting `objectMapper` and converting query parameters map into object solves the problem

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper

  @GetMapping('/pojo')
  void getPojo(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    MyRequest request = objectMapper.convertValue(allRequestParams, MyRequest)
    log.debug("Request received: $myRequest")
  }
...
```

Comment: Darn! I've been looking for this for almost a week now. Thanks mate!